# In-app purchase with phonegap and javascript

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova

Ive created an app with phonegap and I want to add IAP for WP8. Figured I have to create a plugin, but I cant anybody else doing this for WP8. The shop functions are statics awaited in C#, is it doable?

Maybe there is a JS lib for WP IAP? The IAP functions depend on some dlls, how do I include these dlls in my phonegap plugin?